# SmoothScroll to an ID Div on another page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page "link.html" which has an anchor pointing to index.html page `<a href = "index.html?#myInnerLink"`

I want smoothscroll to the div on another page(index.html) which has an Id of "myInnerLink" in jquery .. it is working fine but the problem is that it is scrolling from bottom to top instead of top to bottom to that particular div

"myInnerLink" div is internal in "myDiv" div... Thanks

**link.html**

```
 <a id="mylink" href="index.html?#myInnerLink">Go To MY InnerLink</a>
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="myDiv" class="mydiv">
SomeText here...
<div id="myInnerLink">
 ScrollTo This Div...
</div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var hash = window.location.hash;

            $('#myDiv').animate({
                scrollTop :  $(hash).offset().top
            }, 500);
        };
    });
```

Comment: okay @LegenJerry, I am working on an update.

Comment: code ninja its not working

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using this script below, which is modified and originally came from https://jsfiddle.net/s61x7c4e/

```js
    function doScrolling(element, duration) {
  let bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
      elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
      offset = ((elementRect.top - bodyRect.top) - 40);

  let startingY = window.pageYOffset,
      elementY = offset,
      targetY,
      diff,
      easeInOutCubic,
      start;

  duration = duration || 500;

  // if element is close to page's bottom then window will scroll only to some position above the element...
  targetY = document.body.scrollHeight - elementY < window.innerHeight ? document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight : elementY;
  diff = targetY - startingY;

  easeInOutCubic = function (t) {
      return t < .5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1
  };

  if (!diff) return;

  // bootstrap our animation,
  //  it will get called right before next frame shall be rendered...
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(timestamp) {
      if (!start) start = timestamp;

      let time = timestamp - start, // elapsed milliseconds since start of scrolling...
          percent = Math.min(time / duration, 1); // get percent of completion in range [0, 1]

      // apply the easing, it can cause bad-looking
      //  slow frames in browser performance tool, so be careful...
      percent = easeInOutCubic(percent);

      window.scrollTo(0, startingY + diff * percent);

      // proceed with animation as long as we wanted it to.
      if (time < duration) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
      }
  })
}

document.getElementById('scrollMid').addEventListener('click', function(){
 var element = document.getElementById('middle');
 doScrolling(element, 1000);
});
```

Comment: it is pure javascript no jquery

Comment: yeah, why should you use jQuery when it's not needed?